# Core Animation on Layer-Backed View with rotation

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-animation

Just want to rotate NSView (without animation). Layer backed-view (setWantsLayer=YES). Works with opacity, position. But when I try rotate with

```
[view.layer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:45*M_PI/180] forKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];
```

Nothings happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rotating 0 degrees.

45 * π / 180 = 0.785 which as an `int` is 0.

Change your NSNumber to a float or double

```
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:45*M_PI/180]
```